# How to display a local notification in my app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

My code looks like this:

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    framework = 'At exact boarding time';

    constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            single_notification()
        });
    }
}

function single_notification() {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      id: 1,
      text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
      sound: 'file://sound.mp3',
      data: { secret: 'key_data' }
    });
}
```

I get this error: `Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'`

I would like to have the code be outside of the Homepage class. I created it from within the homepage class, and it gave no errors, but it would not display on my device. I just want to be able to call the function single_notification() from outside the Homepage and display a notification.

---

edit: getting these errors when using Emad Abdou answer:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Make sure you have imported LocalNotifications in your app.module.ts providers
then in your code try this

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
 framework = 'At exact boarding time';

 constructor(
      public platform: Platform,
      private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.single_notification()
    });
  }
}

single_notification() {
  this.localNotifications.schedule({
   id: 1,
   text: 'Single ILocalNotification',
   sound: 'file://sound.mp3',
   data: { secret: 'key_data' }
 });
}
```

Check documentation for more info
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

Comment: I edited my original post, when I do that I get some errors when I import LocalNotification in my constructor. I am unsure, have not had this happen before.

Comment: nevermind, forgot to add /ngx for ionic4. Thanks for the answer!